Installing Pulsar helm chart takes forever
I am following the apache pulsar official guide to run a Pulsar cluster in Kubernetes (https://pulsar.apache.org/docs/3.3.x/getting-started-helm/). As I got into Step 1, created the secret required for installing helm chart through running the provided script, and tried running
helm install \
    --values examples/values-minikube.yaml \
    --namespace pulsar \
    pulsar-mini apache/pulsar

the process gets stuck there forever.
I run kubectl get pods and only found one pod which has a CrashLoopBackOff state and keeps failing and restarting.
NAME                                                READY   STATUS    RESTARTS       AGE
pulsar-mini-kube-prometheu-admission-create-ktpzw   1/1     Running   5 (107s ago)   5m52s

As I took a look in the pod's events, it doesn't show additional information.
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                     From               Message
  ----     ------     ----                    ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  8m21s                   default-scheduler  Successfully assigned pulsar/pulsar-mini-kube-prometheu-admission-create-ktpzw to lima-rancher-desktop
  Normal   Pulled     4m47s (x5 over 8m21s)   kubelet            Container image "registry.k8s.io/ingress-nginx/kube-webhook-certgen:v20221220-controller-v1.5.1-58-g787ea74b6" already present on machine
  Normal   Created    4m47s (x5 over 8m21s)   kubelet            Created container create
  Normal   Started    4m47s (x5 over 8m21s)   kubelet            Started container create
  Warning  BackOff    3m12s (x13 over 7m20s)  kubelet            Back-off restarting failed container create in pod pulsar-mini-kube-prometheu-admission-create-ktpzw_pulsar(59d2a69d-c1c2-4d02-92ee-df46e1deb11c)

